# Can I skip several version during a firmware update?

Tags: solaris, firmware, sparc

I have a SPARC T3-4 server experiencing a known bug (CR 7003014 as described here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19417-01/html/E20814/z40004961296327.html). The solution is to update the firmware to at least version 8.0.4.b. My system is currently on a 3.X version. Can I upgrade straight to the 8.0.4.b release, or do I need to upgrade through each major version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note, the 8.0.4.b version of the firmware has been removed by Oracle.  Download patch 145668-05 to get the 8.0.4.d firmware.

The install docs do not detail any requirements like previous firmware version to install.

Comment: Firmware is just written/flashed to the system from an image.  That is why there is no dependency.